# assign a default value for column ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, migration

i have created a migration for user, later on i added column to my model using

**rails generate migration add_usertype_to_users usertype:string**
which generates following

```
class AddUsertypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :usertype, :string
  end
end
```

now i am trying to assign default value to this usertype as basic.

where it would be better to assign default to this column, i.e inside migration, inside my model, or do i have to create new migration? all the examples i came up with are giving default value at time of creating migration when creating column, please let me know the right way.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting default value in migration is better.

You can define default value like this

```
class AddUsertypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :usertype, :string, default: 'value'
  end
end
```

Comment: i have tried to add default as shown in your code, but when i am trying to create a new record it shows no default value to my usertype column.

Comment: do i have to create new migration or i should make changes in current migration and should use `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: You should rollback the add_column migration.. then run rake db:migrate with default

Answer (score 2):

`add_column :users, :usertype, :string, :default => "your_text"`

Comment: i have tried to add default as shown in your code, but when i am trying to create a new record it shows no default value to my usertype column.

Comment: do i have to create new migration or i should make changes in current migration and should use `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: yes brother you have to create new migration specifying defaults for that column...like this : `def up
    change_column :users, :user_type :string, :default => 'your_string'
  end`

Comment: this code should be in your new migration file, `rake db:migrate` then